# Linux Virtual Machine for Windows 7 that will run Keryx?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, linux-mint

I'm having [a problem](https://superuser.com/questions/669620/how-to-install-packages-onto-linux-mint-without-internet) getting packages onto a Linux computer that doesn't have an internet connection. The accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) suggests [Keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryxproject), which needs a Linux computer with internet to get packages onto the one without.

Are there any virtual machines that I could use to run Linux on Windows 7? Specifically anything that will use Keryx and the computer's internet connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VirtualBox for that. Just install it and install Ubuntu in it.

> VirtualBox is a general-purpose full virtualizer for x86 hardware,
>   targeted at server, desktop and embedded use.

[image]

[Virtualbox Website](https://www.virtualbox.org)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. A note for others: you still need an install disk to boot from.